# Local and remote branch name is same still getting "The upstream branch of your current branch does not match the name of your current branch "

Tags: git

When I do git branch I get that I am on branch v0.2.

```
 git branch
  v0.1
* v0.2
```

But when I do git push it says "The upstream branch of your current branch does not match the name of your current branch "

```
git push

fatal: The upstream branch of your current branch does not match
the name of your current branch.  To push to the upstream branch
on the remote, use

    git push origin HEAD:v1.1

To push to the branch of the same name on the remote, use

    git push origin v0.2
```

Initially I had named this branch v1.1 but now I have renamed it to v0.2 locally and remotely.

How can I fix this once and for all.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Git keeps track of which local branch goes with which remote branch. When you renamed the remote branch, git **lost track** of which remote goes with your local `v0.2` branch. You can fix this using the `--set-upstream-to` or `-u` flag for the branch command.

```
git checkout v0.2
git branch -u origin/v0.2
```

Now when you do `git push`, git will know which branch your local `v0.2` is paired with.

Answer (score 2):

You may have renamed the branch both locally and remotely, but the local branch’s upstream appears to still point to the old name. You can verify this by doing a

```
$ git branch -vv
…
* v0.2   01234abc [origin/v1.1]: Some message
```

… where, if it indeed says `origin/v1.1` in square brackets, your upstream needs to be changed. It should be as easy as specifying the `-u` flag when pushing, though:

```
git push -u origin v0.2
```