# git fetch - "refuse", git pull "forced update, fetch updated current branch head". Local was 2 commits ahead of remote

Tags: git

**Added:**

fetch issue was due to me not understanding how `clone --mirror` works, see my answer below.

**Original:**

I did search. tried to read [Git pull after forced update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813816/git-pull-after-forced-update), [git refusing to fetch into current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236743/git-refusing-to-fetch-into-current-branch), [How can I recover a lost commit in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10099258/how-can-i-recover-a-lost-commit-in-git) but still cannot understand my situation.

Both local and remote on `main` branch currently (by `git status`). `git log` on both confirmed local is ahead of remote by 2 commits. Why git fetch apparently tries to update HEAD?

```
git fetch
fatal: Refusing to fetch into current branch refs/heads/master of non-bare repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

`git pull` did force update and my `main` "lost" recent commits. From linked post I've read to do `git reflog` and `rest --hard` to last commit and I'm back to square one.

Also currently I face another issue (as initially seeing local is ahead I wanted to push) I've just posted as [names match, but: "The upstream branch of your current branch does not match the name of your current branch", git pull wrote "forced update""](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74757673/names-match-but-the-upstream-branch-of-your-current-branch-does-not-match-the):

`git push` outputs "The upstream branch of your current branch does not match the name of your current branch".

What happened to the repo? Why `git pull` does force update by default w/out asking? Why git `push` does not find remote branch?

Added:

I continue see some more interesting things, still w/out understanding why git does not see match of `main` branches, I did `git push origin HEAD:refs/remotes/origin/main` and saw push succeeded:

```
Total x (delta y)
To remote_url 
ref_of_last_remote_commit...ref_of_last_local_commit HEAD -> origin/head
```

But: `git reflog` on remote did not output those new commits!

Answer (score 2):

It’s hard to exactly understand what has gone wrong without knowing the context of your problem (i.e. the status of your git repository), but you said “ `git push` outputs ‘The upstream branch of your current branch does not match the name of your current branch’.” and that could be a clue.

Assuming your local branch is named `main` and your remote repository is named `origin` (you can verify this by `git remote -v`), the common setup is that your local branch `main` should be tracking remote branch `origin/main`. Check by typing `git branch -vv`. If they don’t match, try using `git push -u origin main` to make your remote branch name match with that of your local’s.

Or if `origin/main` already exists, you can try rename your local branch to some unique name (`git checkout -b <the_unique_name>` after you have committed everything locally) and do `git push -u origin <the_unique_name>`.

Answer (score 0):

I've made that repo with `git clone --mirror`, now with help of @torek in [Why line with "fetch" in git config effects how `git branch --set-upstream-to` work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74785335/why-line-with-fetch-in-git-config-effects-how-git-branch-set-upstream-to-w) I understand it was root cause of results/issues as `--mirror` sets in `.git/config` : `fetch = +refs/*:refs/*` (which I left as it was, but I've changed `core.bare=false`).

1. `fetch` refused as I asked it to update all refs, including current branch.
2. With fetch set for mirroring, `git pull` is expected to update all local refs with ones from remote, hence `forced update`