# git chaining: git push from local updated remote's remotes ref. Why and how was it possible?

Tags: git

I'm facing weird (IMO) issues with my repo and start to question what I assumed. That is chaining of repos. Web search "git chaining repos" gave https://serverfault.com/questions/186161/possible-to-chain-git-repos where the answer "yes, of cause".

Now I just did `git push origin HEAD:refs/remotes/origin/main` in local (1st repo), in `.git/config` of 1st there is URL for `origin` (2nd repo).

In that 2nd repo in `.git/config` there is URL of 3rd repo as `origin`. But after `push` which outputted several objects in delta, I did not see those by `git reflog` on 2nd. Instead I saw in 2nd in `refs/remotes/origin/main` file hash of last commit pushed from 1st repo.

How do you think that happened? Maybe some internal `damage' to repo(s)? Other issues that lead me to investigate are in [git fetch - "refuse", git pull "forced update, fetch updated current branch head". Local was 2 commits ahead of remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74757962/git-fetch-refuse-git-pull-forced-update-fetch-updated-current-branch-head). TIA

git version 2.25.1

Added:

Yesterday repos seemed fine, I recall I first synced 1st and 2nd, then 2rd and 3nd, today I wanted to sync 1st and 2nd.

The only unusual thing I did I recall today after pull from 2nd to 1st there was a conflict, I did `git reset FILE` in 1st for file with that conflict and replaced (copied to repo folder) the file from backup outside of git.

Answer (score 0):

`git` did what it was told to, push to `origin HEAD:refs/remotes/origin/main`, which is remote on remote.

When troubleshooting I noticed in `.git/config` entry for `main` was different, extra `remotes`. Apparently it set main to track main on remote's remote (further down the chain).

Also I recall I saw `git-branch --set-upstream-to=main main` produces effect of setting `main` branch to track origin's main and `git-branch --set-upstream-to=origin/main main` produce `config` change as described above. I was because I've made repo with `git clone --mirror` which sets refs translation in `.git/config` as `fetch = +refs/*:refs/*` whereas with regular `clone`: `fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`.

I think one needs to look attentively to output of the command to know the result.

To find out the cause of the issue included me running `strace`, seeing code only reads `.git/config` in user home, `.git/config`, `.git/HEAD`, `.git/refs/heads/main` and then realizing `.git/config` entry differs from entries for other repo (extra `/remotes`).

Comment: `git-branch --set-upstream-to=main main`: this is valid but a *very bad idea*. It sets the upstream of `main` to be `main`. That's not a remote-tracking name, that's a local branch name. You can set the upstream of a branch `br2` to be local branch `br1` if you like; this means `git merge` and `git rebase` while on `br2` will use `br1` as the missing argument. It's not good with push and pull though since those are meant for transferring commits to/from *another repository* and in this case, the "other Git" is *your own* repository, so there's never anything to transfer.

Comment: There are a few special purpose uses for `git push . br1:br2` or `git fetch . br2:br1`, if you want to attempt fast-forwarding one local branch name via another local branch name. But that's not what you want here. (Note that in this case, the "URL" of `.` refers to the current directory => use the local Git repository as if it were a second Git repository).

Comment: @torek, thanks for trying to help. I now guess all issues are from some perculiar set of refs and config file of the repo. I'm trying to reperform with simple repos from init/clone and cannot arrive at my issues (yet).